# Filling missing values in a dataframe based on first valid non-null column

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to fill the null values in the first column in a pandas dataframe with the first non-null column value in each row and can't seem to get this to work

here's an example

```
dfr = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan], 'b':[4, np.nan, np.nan, 7, np.nan], 'c':[4, 5, 6, 7, np.nan], 'd':[3, 1, 3, 9, 12]})


#This is what my original data frame looks like

dfr
Out[107]: 
     a    b    c   d
0  NaN  4.0  4.0   3
1  NaN  NaN  5.0   1
2  3.0  NaN  6.0   3
3  NaN  7.0  7.0   9
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  12


#Here's what I would like the output to look like

dfr
Out[107]: 
     a    b    c   d
0  4.0  4.0  4.0   3
1  5.0  NaN  5.0   1
2  3.0  NaN  6.0   3
3  7.0  7.0  7.0   9
4  12  NaN  NaN  12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `bfill`

```
dfr.a=dfr.bfill(1).a
dfr
      a    b    c   d
0   4.0  4.0  4.0   3
1   5.0  NaN  5.0   1
2   3.0  NaN  6.0   3
3   7.0  7.0  7.0   9
4  12.0  NaN  NaN  12
```